# Check if variables are null in where clause using case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have declared in MSSQL 2 variables that can be `null` so:

```
DECLARE @startCheckDate VARCHAR(10) = '2015-10-20'  --this can be null
DECLARE @endCheckDate VARCHAR(10) = '2015-10-31' -- this can be null
```

Variables can be both `null` or both not `null` no other option.

Now in the `where` condition in my query I want to check if those values are `null` using `case` I'm trying:

```
declare @since varchar(10) = '2015-10-20' --this is never null so it do not matter

select doc.id 
from document 
where
doc.active = 'T'
and 
(
case when @startCheckDate is not null and @endCheckDate is not null
then
    doc.modifiedDate > @since or (doc.modifiedDate between @startCheckDate and @endCheckDate)
else
    doc.modifiedDate > @since
end)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think you can replace the whole case part by just: doc.modifiedDate > @ since or (doc.modifiedDate between @ startCheckDate and @ endCheckDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of this question is correct, you could do this with an `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause as opposed to using `CASE`.

**NOTE:** You should compare `DATE` values as dates. I've added conversions to change the values from strings to `DATE` values, but it would be easier if the values were of type `DATE` in the first place in the variables and the columns that you are comparing to.

```
SELECT  doc.id
FROM    document
WHERE   doc.active = 'T'
        AND ( -- compare doc.modifiedDate > @since if start and end dates NULL
              ( @startCheckDate IS NULL
                AND @endCheckDate IS NULL
                AND CONVERT(DATE, doc.modifiedDate) > CONVERT(DATE, @since)
              )
              OR ( -- use between if start and end dates not NULL
                   @startCheckDate IS NOT NULL
                   AND CONVERT(DATE, doc.modifiedDate) 
                       BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @startCheckDate) 
                           AND CONVERT(DATE, @endCheckDate)
                 )
            )
```

Looking at your code though, it look like you have the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` checks the wrong way round, which I've swapped around in my sample.

With this, only the portion of the `WHERE` clause that meets the conditions is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, when I need to dynamically build where clause, I build the query and run it using Exec. It helps me to reduce all these case statements which may be expensive in terms of performance. Something similar below. This way you can build where clause dynamically

```
declare @since varchar(10) = '2015-10-20' --this is never null so it do not matter
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

if @startCheckDate is not null and @endCheckDate is not null
begin
    set @sql = 'select doc.id from document where doc.active = ''T'' and doc.modifiedDate > ' + @since + ' or (doc.modifiedDate between ' + @startCheckDate + ' and ' + @endCheckDate + ')' 
end
else 
begin
    set @sql = 'select doc.id from document where doc.active = ''T'' and  doc.modifiedDate > ' + @since     
end
exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score -2):

Any comparison to null is false so the case is not needed

```
( doc.modifiedDate > @since or doc.modifiedDate between @startCheckDate and @endCheckDate )
```

Comment: Any comparison to null is `UNKNOWN`, not `FALSE`. This is trivially observable by wrapping such an expression with `NOT()` and observing that the result isn't then `TRUE`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever One - there is not not here.    Two - I would include NOT() in "ANY comparison".

Comment: No, I mean if you have `X = NULL`, the result is *not* `FALSE`, since if you replace it with `NOT (X = NULL)` you will not produce `TRUE`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly, ANY comparison to null (including NOT) returns false.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It produces the third logic value for SQL's [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) - `UNKNOWN`. It *doesn't* produce `FALSE`. If it did produce `FALSE`, then applying `NOT` to such an expression ought to produce `TRUE` - but it doesn't. Your statement that such an expression evaluates as `FALSE` is *wrong*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good for you, you got your down vote.   I know how it works.    Not has no bearing on the stated question.

Comment: You got a downvote because the first statement in your answer is factually incorrect. I've tried to point you towards understanding *why* it's incorrect, but you're not willing to listen. If it wasn't for that, the rest of your answer would be okay. Good luck explaining how `OR` and `AND` work in the face of your belief that comparisons with `NULL` produce `FALSE`, and with explaining the differences between how predicates are evaluated in `WHERE` clauses versus in `CHECK` constraints, without understanding three-valued logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But I am not explaining where, check,  ....  It a simple valid answer to the stated question.